# SSL setup for opencart Multi store, Multiple domain names on one server

Tags: ssl, opencart

I have an OpenCart multi store setup and i need to know which type of SSL to purchase. basically all domains are sitting on a single domain/server/single IP. do i need a SAN, wildcard or each store need to have their own IP and own SSL?

current setup is:

- www.mainstore.com
- www.2ndstore.com
- www.3rdstore.com
- www.4thstore.com

all stores use the same folder `public_html/mainstore.com`

Answer (score 0):

alright ive figured it out, for setup similar to this you can use Positive SSL Multi-Domain.